# Eclipse not finding gcc?

Tags: eclipse, gcc

I did a fresh install of my computer, I installed a new Eclipse and imported a program into my workspace. The program was working fine before but now I get this message when I try to compile

```
Program "gcc -std=gnu99" not found in PATH
```

I checked if gcc is on my PATH variable and it is

```
user@computer:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin
```

and

```
user@computer:~$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be looking for an executable named "`gcc -std=gnu99`", which of course doesn't exist.

I don't know Eclipse very well, but presumably you have to specify the command name `gcc` and the argument(s) `-std=gnu99` separately.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2183888/827263) discusses setting gcc options in Eclipse.

From that and my own brief experiments, compiler options are set for each project. After selecting a project, follow this sequence of menus:

Project --> Properties -->C/C++ Build --> Settings --> GCC C compiler

In my installation, I have:

```
Command: gcc
All options: -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
```

If you have "-std=gnu99" in the "Command" setting, delete it and add it to the "All options" setting.

This is for Eclipse 3.5.2 running on Debian; the menu hierarchy might be different on yours.

If that's not it, you might also want to check your environment variables:

```
$ env | grep gnu99
```

Comment: I thought about that but I can't find where that command is specified. In the compile options I have gcc -fopenmp but nothing with -std=gnu99. I loked into the makefile but I couldn't find it either. Very weird.

Comment: Did you specify `"gcc -std=gnu99"` yourself at some point? Does it appear in some environment variable (`printenv | grep gnu99`)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll try that when I'm at work on Monday but I'm pretty sure I looked into the GCC C compiler section already and there was no "-std=gnu99" option there. I'll check the environment variables too.

Comment: @Atirag: `-std=gnu99` isn't the default, so *something* must be telling Eclipse to use it. Try `grep -rl std=gnu99 ~/.eclipse`

Comment: Ok I tried everything you recommended to me but I couldn't find gnu99 anywhere...